# How do I update items of different types in a XAML ListBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm working on a WPF application in C#.
The application has 3 different UserControls (Foo1, Foo2 and Foo3), each one has at least one TextBox.
On the main window, there's a ListBox that has these UserControls as its items; all in different quantities and in no particular order.

If I change the Text property on any of these item's TextBoxes, the change is not visible until the ListBox.Items collection is changed (i.e. an item is added or removed).

How do I get the ListBox to update? I've tried giving the UserControls dependency properties (with the flag FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender) that updates the textbox's text, but that didn't do anything. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and invoking the PropertyChanged event had no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to change the Text, this changed Text appears in `ListBox` without problems.

UserControl :

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata("unset"));

    }
```

Window1 :

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    IList<UserControl1> ucList = new[] { new UserControl1() { Text = "some text" }, new UserControl1() { Text = "some more value" } };

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        LstBox.ItemsSource = ucList;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ucList[0].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        /* Now textbox shows current date-time */
    }
}
```

[image: UserControl updation in ListBox]

Comment: Thanks! This answer really helped me out a lot! I'm an experienced C# developer but WPF is still new to me. This ItemSource property seems very usable and I'm definitely going to implement this in my application. I found out that using an ObservableCollection of UIElements will also automatically update the list when something is added or removed.

Comment: adding/removing is diff than updating the item itself.

Comment: True, but the IList is of a fixed length and using non-observable collections causes the list to not automatically update upon changing the collection. But thanks to your answer I got it all to work.